# Changin a div border with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, border

I have created a div programaticaly using.

```
var Element;
Element = document.createElement('div');
```

Now I want to change the right and bottom border to "#CCCCCC 1px solid".

I don't want to use a library for this and using CSS classes is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element.setAttribute("style", "bottom-right: #CCCCCC 1px solid"); ?
```

Answer (score 3):

```
element.style.borderRight = element.style.borderBottom = "#CCCCCC 1px solid";
```